# How to connect Xamarin.Forms app to mysql database without webservices

Tags: mysql, xamarin.forms

I am required to develop a cross-platform app for use within an internal network. The app must connect to a MySQL database within that network. I must do this without touching any server on the network (I cannot setup web APIs within the network). I have chosen Xamarin.Forms for development.

I searched for ways to integrate MySQL directly with Xamarin.Forms and most people rightly recommended to use web APIs. Unfortunately, that's not possible in my case. In some answers here on SO, I found the Nuget package `Xamarin.MySql.Data`.

However, when I add it to the project, build fails with this error:

```
NU1202  Package Xamarin.MySql.Data 1.0.1 is not compatible with uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299) / win10-arm. Package Xamarin.MySql.Data 1.0.1 supports:
  - monoandroid (MonoAndroid,Version=v0.0)
  - monotouch (MonoTouch,Version=v0.0)
  - xamarinios (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v0.0)
```

I understand that this is a compatibility issue.

What other options are available?
Thanks.

Comment: ... define *"internal network"*, what is dat a LAN or private netwerk with VPN / SSL tunnel usage

Comment: *"What other options are available? Thanks."* `Xamarin.MySql.Data`  is just build on top off [MySQL's .NET connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.10.html)..   Programming guide is found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming.html)

Comment: ... also you can take a look into [Apache cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) -> *"Mobile apps with HTML, CSS & JS

Target multiple platforms with one code base"* ... But i might be the case you need to [write](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html) your own plugin to connect to MySQL..

Comment: By 'internal network', I meant a LAN connection. Ok, so the MySQL connector should work just fine? That's what I'm currently trying. Thank you

Comment: Remember that Xamarin.MySql.Data owner is an individual developer called snowwolf725 and has no updates since 02/01/2018 https://www.nuget.org/profiles/snowwolf725 it works fine with Xamarin, but it's not an official package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the official documentation of the MySQL Connector for .NET it runs on any version of .NET, hence you should be able to use it from a *Xamarin.Forms* app.

> MySQL Connector/NET runs on any platform that supports the .NET Standard (.NET Framework, .NET Core, and Mono) ([see the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-installation.html))

You may [install the connector from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) and then start using it.

If you are used to ADO.NET (or willing to learn it), you can then start using the `MySqlConnection` class. Please see the following **very basic example**:

```cs
List<MyObject> result = new List<MyObject>();

using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString); // C# 8!
connection.Open();

using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT id, name FROM fooBar WHERE deleted = 0"; // whatever

using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{
    result.Add(new MyObject
                   {
                       Id = reader.GetUInt64("id"), // the parameter is the name of the column
                       Name = reader.GetString("name"),
                   });

}

return result;
```

(see [this page on connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) if you don't have any idea how `connectionString` shall look like. **Please note** that the MySQL instance has to be accessible from the devices that shall use this connection.)

If you prefer using EF, you'll have to [install this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore/).

Comment: Thanks Paul. I have used the library several times when running .NET Core apps. I wasn't sure it would work with Xamarin despite targeting .NET Standard 2.0, especially since I found no reference to it in my search. Thank you.

Comment: @staa99 I haven't used it neither with Xamarin, but I'd assume that it should work.

Comment: @PaulKertscher, I am getting "System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception" at "connection.Open". Could you please tell how to resolve this